# Node.js and Oracle DB select query getting empty array in rows

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

```
   const result = await connection.execute(
       `SELECT * from no_example `, [], { maxRows: 1000 } // bind value for :id
   );
```

but in result i always get empty rows

Answer (score 0):

If you are inserting rows in another tool, or another program.  Make sure that you COMMIT the data:

```
SQL> create table t (c number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t (c) values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.
```

If you are insert using Node.js, look at the [`autoCommit`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#propdbisautocommit) attribute and [`connection.commit()`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#commit) function.  Also see the node-oracledb documentation on [Transaction Management](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#transactionmgt).

Unrelated to your problem, but you almost certainly shouldn't be using `maxRows`.  By default node-oracledb will return all rows.  If you don't want all, then add some kind of WHERE clause or [row-limiting clause](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#pagingdata) to your query.  If you expect a big number of rows, then use a [result set](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#resultsethandling) so you can access consecutive batches of rows.